# Reading a dataset file(Hex values) onto a block of memory

Tags: c++, dataset, ifstream

I have a block of code that is trying to read the data from a dataset on to a randomly allocated block of memory. I don't know what exactly is inside the dataset but they access  matrix values(Hex values) and put on to a memory location. And it works fine!

```
for (unsigned int i=0; i<header->numImg; ++i)
    {
        const unsigned int cur_proj = i; // absolute projection number

        // read mx
        double* const pMatx = MatrixBuffers + cur_proj * 12;
        ifData.read((char*) (pMatx), 12 * sizeof(double));
        }
```

where MatrixBuffers is

```
double** MatrixBuffers = new double* [header.numImg];   
MatrixBuffers[0] = new double[header.numImg * 12];  
for (unsigned int i=1; i<header.glb_numImg; ++i) {
    MatrixBuffers[i] = MatrixBuffers[0] + i * 12;
}
```

As you see MatrixBuffers is randomly allocated memory, say the staring address of which is 6000. My question is, how do I know from where exactly is the data being read from the 2.5GB dataset (From what location)? Is it from 6000 or some-other address? How can I control the access pattern of dataset?
**************EDITS***********************
To make it clear, there is a read operation before this and one after this. The one before this starts from 1st byte till 12th byte. If the above code has to start from 13th byte, how to let compiler know that pMatx starting value is 13th byte in the dataset?
 Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ifData.read is a sequential read operation, and so each read will input the next 12 double values into one of the allocated arrays of double. I'm not sure I understand your problem.

Comment: Alright, to make it clear there is one read operation before this that starts from the 1st value in the dataset till 12th byte and one after this. I wanna know, from what location in the dataset will this access pattern start from. If it is from the 13th byte, how will the compiler know from this : ifData.read((char*) (pMatx), 12 * sizeof(double))

Comment: The position is maintained by the ifstream assuming that this is the type in the declaration of ifData.

Comment: The thing is, this code reads 12 doubles and then seeks to a position 4MB away and does the same operation. That seekg was supposed to be in that for loop. And my third read operation, reads data that's in between. So, are you saying my third read operation will automatically know to start the read after 12 doubles ?

Comment: What does "in between" mean? File position? How do you know that it is read from "in between". - A seekg changes the position for the next read, otherwise one read follows another. - If you don't show the actual code you won't get good answers.

Comment: @laune: Please follow this link. I have created another thread that has complete information. I really appreciate the help!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302284/reading-a-dataset-filehex-values-onto-a-block-of-memory-part-2